# Network layer 1 failure

Tags: debian, ubuntu, networking, networkmanager

I updated 3 machines, one debian 9 and two ubuntu and all have completely lost network access. The Debian upgrade failed halfway, but the ubuntu ones seem to have gone properly.

The failure seems to be at layer 1: the switch sees the connection ('up'), but fails to receive a mac address from the machines.
The machines themselves show the links as 'no-carrier'. The lights on the RJ45 are lit. The machines have 2 different network cards and the results are the same.

I'm completely stumped as to why 3 different systems with 3 different network cards with 2 different OSes would fail in the same way on the same day.

lshw shows `*-network:0 DISABLED` on all. dmesg doesn't show anything wrong with the drivers (which I see loaded with `lsmod)`.

Doing a `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` drops me in emergency mode.

Is there a very low level service I should check ? I'm lost.

I should add that when booting with a LiveCD, the network is FINE.

EDIT:
To expand on my comment, while going through the logs of the ubuntu systems, I saw a message `"A start job is running for dev-sdb1.device"` and I noticed that this disk wasn't being mounted. Looking in `/etc/fstab` and `lsblk` and `blkid` I saw that this disk had moved from another name (say `/dev/sdc1`) during the upgrade (why?!?). So I updated the fstab to use the UUID instead of the device name. I rebooted and the network came back!

I'm totally nonplussed as to why the network would utterly fail if a minor data disk won't mount.

EDIT:

```
# ethtool -i eth0
driver: tg3
version: 3.137
firmware-version: FFV20.2.17 bc 5720-v1.39
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:01:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-tests: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

Comment: On each network interface, what are the outputs of commands `ethtool -i <interface>` and `ethtool <interface>`? Are the network interfaces of a type that would require firmware, and if they are, have the appropriate firmware packages been installed?

Comment: Unfortunately ethtool is not installed

Comment: Solved on the 2 ubuntu systems: it was a renamed /dev/hd disk (not even system disk) that failed to mount and apparently caused the network to failed. Why? I have no idea. The problem remains on Debian.

Comment: The title is misleading, like you've already determined that your problem is exactly "layer 1 failure". (and, not that we need to get into that, but switches are layer 2 btw)

Comment: Just to clear things up, various network commands showing 'no-carrier' while the cable is in and the other side shows a connection should be a Layer 1 failure or am I mistaken ?

Comment: @telcoM I managed to install ethtool. Output in original msg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 Ubuntu systems:

To expand on my comment, while going through the logs, I saw a message `"A start job is running for dev-sdb1.device"` and I noticed that this disk wasn't being mounted. Looking in `/etc/fstab` and `lsblk` and `blkid` I saw that this disk had moved from another name (say `/dev/sdc1`) during the upgrade (why?!?). So I updated the fstab to use the UUID instead of the device name. I rebooted and the network came back!

I'm totally nonplussed as to why the network would utterly fail if a minor data disk won't mount. But problem solved.

On the Debian system it was a lot more complicated:

I mounted a Debian 10 DVD. Used `apt-cdrom` to enable it in `/etc/apt/sources` and commented out all other (now useless network) sources. Manage to finish updating the system with `apt update; apt dist-upgrade`. I then reinstalled the [networks drivers](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/) (tg3 and bnx2x) with `dpkg -i...`. When doing that the eth0 and eth6 actually switched places, so I had to update `/etc/network/interfaces`.
After a reboot the network came back ! I just had to reinstate `/etc/apt/sources` and update and upgrade again.

Comment: You posted this as an answer, but this is not an answer. You should edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `systemd` and its `systemd-fstab-generator` will treat all local disks listed in `/etc/fstab` as essential, and if one of those cannot be mounted at boot time, the system will drop into emergency mode. If some of your local disks are non-essential, you should consider explicitly marking them as such, by using the `nofail` mount option.

You said "doing a `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` drops you in emergency mode", but are you sure the system wasn't already in emergency mode before that? Sometimes other messages might appear on the console just as the emergency mode prompt appears, possibly obscuring the notification that you're actually in emergency mode.

When a local filesystem that is not marked with a `nofail` mount option fails to mount, that means the system will fail to reach the `local-fs.target`, which is a pre-requisite of reaching `sysinit.target`. The initialization of networking happens (at least on Debian/Ubuntu) only *after* `sysinit.target` has been reached. See the diagram at `man 7 bootup` to understand the various `.target`s that act as fixed points in a `systemd`-based boot process.

If your network interfaces are managed by `NetworkManager`, on Debian `NetworkManager.service` is started only after `sysinit.target`. If you're using classic Debian `/etc/network/interfaces` to configure your network interfaces, then `networking.service` will apply the settings... but even that has an `After=local-fs.target` dependency on it, so if `local-fs.target` is never reached (i.e. one of the local filesystems fails to mount and it's not marked non-essential), then **networking will not be started.**

So, it appears that your "network layer 1 failure" may have been no failure at all: the network adapter drivers were apparently loaded, but they just hadn't been told to activate the interfaces yet, because an earlier local filesystem failure prevented the system from getting that far in the boot process.

The classic `/dev/sdX` disk names are assigned as disk devices are detected, by default in a strict first-come, first-served basis. Each storage controller driver will decide for itself how it will present the devices it manages to the rest of the kernel at driver start-up time. SATA and SAS drivers might go by the hardware-based numbering of individual SATA/SAS links; FibreChannel HBA drivers might go by WWID order or have some pre-defined ordering; hardware RAID controllers might go by the order in which the various RAID sets have been defined. If you have multiple storage controllers, the loading order of their driver modules will play a significant part too. And then there's a possibility that a disk may have been hot-plugged, and will have received a device name that will be "out-of-order"; unless something is done to make that name persistent, such a disk will take its standard place in the detection order in the next reboot, potentially bumping all other disks that come after it by one spot.

This is one of the reasons why the current recommended practice is to not use `/dev/sdX` names in `/etc/fstab`: you should use `UUID=` or `LABEL=` syntax, or the various `/dev/disk/by-*/*` names instead, according to what you consider to be the primary identifier of the disk or filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It's gonna take a while to digest as I'm still a SystemV kind of guy and never really understood the logic underlying systemd. But a quick question: when something goes wrong with systemd (such as the network not starting), how do you diagnose it ?!?

Comment: @dargaud That would be a question worth an entire question post of its own, but you might start with `systemctl status` and `systemctl --failed` to see the overall status and the list of failed units, respectively. Then `systemctl status <service name>` to get the error messages a particular service produced as it failed. `systemctl list-units '*.target'` might also be a handy overview of "how far did the current boot attempt get?"